# git is not adding files, log included

Tags: git

I've added all files of my wordpress project, yet my custom theme folder isn't being added to git.
I prefer to use PHPStorm's Git engine for convenience purposes and never use force commands (prefer not to, if avoidable).

**Git Directory:**

[image]

This is my latest Log print from PHPStorm:

`09:11:07.306: git -c core.quotepath=false add --ignore-errors -- package.json functions.php footer.php npm-debug.log.386200178 sidebar.php index.php header.php style.css`

And this is my Git ignore:

```
# Created by .ignore support plugin (hsz.mobi)
### WordPress template
*.log
.htaccess
sitemap.xml
sitemap.xml.gz
wp-config.php
wp-content/advanced-cache.php
wp-content/backup-db/
wp-content/backups/
wp-content/blogs.dir/
wp-content/cache/
wp-content/upgrade/
wp-content/uploads/
wp-content/wp-cache-config.php
wp-content/plugins/hello.php
.idea
/readme.html
/license.txt

### Node template
# Logs
logs

npm-debug.log*

# Runtime data
pids
*.pid
*.seed

# Directory for instrumented libs generated by jscoverage/JSCover
lib-cov

# Coverage directory used by tools like istanbul
coverage

# Grunt intermediate storage (http://gruntjs.com/creating-plugins#storing-task-files)
.grunt

# node-waf configuration
.lock-wscript

# Compiled binary addons (http://nodejs.org/api/addons.html)
build/Release

# Dependency directory
# https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/faq#should-i-check-my-node-modules-folder-into-git
node_modules
```

**Current git status:**

```
Initial commit

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

        new file:   footer.php
        new file:   functions.php
        new file:   header.php
        new file:   index.php
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/CHANGELOG.md
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/Gruntfile.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/LICENSE
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/README.md
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css.map
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css.map
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css.map
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/npm.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/.jshintrc
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/bs-commonjs-generator.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/bs-glyphicons-data-generator.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/bs-lessdoc-parser.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/bs-raw-files-generator.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/change-version.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/configBridge.json
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/npm-shrinkwrap.json
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/grunt/sauce_browsers.yml
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/affix.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/alert.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/button.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/carousel.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/collapse.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/dropdown.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/modal.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/popover.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/scrollspy.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/tab.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/tooltip.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/js/transition.js
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/alerts.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/badges.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/breadcrumbs.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/button-groups.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/buttons.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/carousel.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/close.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/code.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/component-animations.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/dropdowns.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/forms.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/glyphicons.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/grid.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/input-groups.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/jumbotron.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/labels.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/list-group.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/media.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/alerts.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/background-variant.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/border-radius.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/buttons.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/center-block.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/clearfix.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/forms.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/gradients.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/grid-framework.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/grid.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/hide-text.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/image.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/labels.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/list-group.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/nav-divider.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/nav-vertical-align.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/opacity.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/pagination.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/panels.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/progress-bar.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/reset-filter.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/reset-text.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/resize.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/responsive-visibility.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/size.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/tab-focus.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/table-row.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/text-emphasis.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/text-overflow.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins/vendor-prefixes.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/modals.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/navbar.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/navs.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/normalize.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/pager.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/pagination.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/panels.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/popovers.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/print.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/progress-bars.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/responsive-embed.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/responsive-utilities.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/scaffolding.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/tables.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/theme.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/thumbnails.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/tooltip.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/type.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/utilities.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/variables.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/less/wells.less
        new file:   node_modules/bootstrap/package.json
        new file:   npm-debug.log.386200178
        new file:   package.json
        new file:   sidebar.php
        new file:   style.css
```

Comment: whats the o/p of git status command and how you adding the folder.

Comment: can you add your directory structure and the location of your custom theme folder?

Comment: git status added to question

Comment: @andrei-macarie git/directory structure all added to question.

Comment: Have you tried using `git check-ignore wp-ecommerce/wp-content/themes/myCommerce/index.php` for example, just to double check that there is no unexpected ignore rule which is ignoring that file?

Comment: don't forget to ignore node_modules folder (eg: add **/**/node_modules to .gitignore). You don't want that one to get on GIT.

Comment: Go to command line on the root of your git repo and type "git add ." then look at status "git status". Let us know if everything was added.

Comment: Ok, I have fixed everything by deleting the whole folder, where that wasn't enough since PHPStorm needs to 'invalidate-cache' since it 'remembered' different git configs, even after delete and restart, so that sure was a hassle that originated from using PHPStorm's Git engine, which is usually great to use, but once it goes haywire, you're in a world of pain. Sorry I couldn't come up with a more exhaustive solution, other than the friggin delete/destroy all button... :/ thanks for the help gents.